Could you go up front? VS Could you go to the up front? VS "Could you go to the front"?
A man driving a boat in a sea with particles of ice asks his friend:

Could you go up front and just tell me left or right, please?

"go up front" caught my attention, because it sparked 2 questions in my mind:
1- The driver wants his friend to go to the front part of the boat. So I think, "up" is not connected to "go" as in a phrasal verb (go up), so it is part of the noun "up front", but then it should have the article "the", because there is only one "upfront of the boat". So why didn't he say "go to THE up-front"?
2- Instead of saying "go up front", could I say "go to the front" in order to mean the same?

Most people will say that on a boat you go forward to the bow (rhymes with 'how'). Also left is port and right is starboard. Anyone sailing (not 'driving') a boat at sea should know these things.

FORWARD - Toward the bow of the vessel (pronounced “forrard”). Also, particles of ice --> ice floes. Mere particles would need little avoidance.

@WeatherVane - in the West Country (England), maybe elsewhere, in the 1970s, you could buy little boxes of matches made in Gloucester, branded 'England's Glory'. On the back used to be inspirational messages, jokes, etc. One of the latter was: "Middle-aged lady on ship: I'd like to speak to the captain. Crewman: He's forrard, Miss. Lady: I don't mind; I've been out with medical students.

@MichaelHarvey - Those matches were certainly on sale in Derbyshire in the '50s and '60s - my mother used to light the fire with them.

@KateBunting - Grandma in Castle Donington used Swan Vestas. "Near Derby" we had to put on letters, because although it is in Leicestershire (just), Derby is the post town.


We'll meet you at the movie theater to see the Halloween horror flick. Where will you be sitting?
-- We'll be sitting down front.

or

I really have to pee. Where is the rest room in this supermarket?
-- I think it's up front near the customer service counter.

These are not nouns but prepositions,  locative adverbs in old-school parlance.   front is like aft in that regard.
